# About serialize vector<int32_t> in a TCP buffer?

Tags: c++, sockets, portability, tcp

I wanna prepend the size of the vector in the buffer. But I don't know exactly what the type of the size is. After all, std::size_t can't be a fixed size. In my mind, I intend to use uint64_t instead. Then the buffer would like this:

```
8 bytes length | 4 bytes element1 | 4 bytes element2 | ... |
```

Now the question is uint64_t doesn't mean std::size_t. Any better ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. If you want to use four bytes or eight bytes or whatever to encode the size in some particular endianness or format, then just do that. What's the issue? You can use `size_t` to hold the size -- what difference does it make what type you use as long as it can hold the size?

Comment: Also, to be portable, make sure you get predictable endianness, e.g. use htonl() for the 32-bit entities before sending them on the socket.

Comment: @David Schwartz The question is that I don't know what the size of the vector is. I can't just use an uint64_t  variable to hold that size, and then write this variable into the buffer.

Comment: What's wrong with `uint64_t size_to_serialise = my_vector.size();`, then writing out the 8 bytes of `size_to_serialize`?  In other words, if `size_t` is less than 8 bytes, simply let the standard conversion extend it to `uint64_t` (all the high order bits will be clear/0).

Comment: @NiklausTseng Use `size_t` to hold the size. You can still use 8 bytes for the length in the wire protocol. How you hold native multi-byte types in your code has nothing to do with how you arrange individual bytes in the buffer you transmit. The point of writing serialization/deserialization code is to carefully place each byte according to the requirements of the wire format which *must* be specified at the byte level.

Comment: Pick either `uint32_t` or `uint64_t`, Before serializing check if `vector.size()` fits in whatever type you picked, and throw an exception otherwise. This will work even if in 100 years `size_t` becomes 128 bits.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any type you want so long as it can hold the value you are using. Since it's already a `size_t`, just keep it that way. Decide how many bytes you want to use to represent the value and what value you need each byte to be and write code to encode/decode each byte correctly.

Comment: I was about to say: "This is a terrible idea.  Your size_t is probably 64 bits.  The size_t on my little ARM processor is 32 bits.  I think you can still get devices with size_t of 16 bits."  But I misunderstood.  You meant "use size_t, but encode that as 8 octets when you save to the TCP buffer (and if size_t is 32 bits, 4 of the octets will necessarily end up as zeros)". - Agreed.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there.  No current platform uses size_t greater than 64 bits (and it would take several days to transfer 64bits worth of int32 over experimental 100TBit fibre).  The steps are:

1. `const uint64_t len = vec.length();`
2. Write the eight bytes into your tcp buffer in a defined order.
3. Write the four bytes of each int into the tcp buffer in a defined order.
4. Send.

Note that the last two steps will have to be in a loop for more than a few thousand elements..